# How to change name on Google Account

Tags: google-account

Following the steps outlaid here:

https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/27442?hl=en

I signed in, clicked edit under *Personal Info*, and I can see the *First Name* and *Last Name* but I can't edit them… they are just text. The info at the top says “View and edit email and phone settings”.

I'm using Chrome, so a browser compatibility issue is unlikely.

Is this a bug?

Is there another way of doing this? (I don't have Google+.)

Answer (score 1):

As per Google Products Forum update, you can change the account name using various option as before.

- Your Google account page.

  Google → *Accounts* → *Edit Profile* → click on your name and change it → *Save changes*
- Check in *Settings* for your *Send mail as* name to make sure it's correct.

  Open *Settings* → *Accounts* → *Send mail as* → click Edit info and change the name.
- You should also search for yourself in your contacts

  Contacts manager → search for your own email address → make sure the name is correctly listed
- Check the spelling of your name in your back-up account.

  If you have a recovery email, Gmail sometimes looks at the name in that account, so make sure it's not connected to an account you own.

Please refer the source for detailed information.

Source: [Google Products Forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/gmail/ukyMoEZgwVk/tMPTjXu9q48J).

Comment: Thanks but the top one isn't working for me; the name fields are just text (not clickable or editable). This isn't really an email account so changing 'Send mail as' won't help.. and is a bit of a hack anyway. Searching for the name in contacts also reveals the same unwanted name and there is no back-up account.

Comment: I have upvoted however, for the well constructed options that may assist another user.